# Проверка на наличие картинки, если нет, то картинка по умолчанию

Tags: php, html

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно задать проверку на наличие картинки элемента. Картинка для умолчания будет лежать в /bitrix/templates/site/images/wip.jpg. То есть если не загружено ни одной картинки для элемента, то выводилась вышеуказанная. Местонахождение интересующего блока в строке, где "width" => 534, "height" => 307 это и есть упоминание о нужном разделе.

```
<div class='catalog-detail' data-val='<?=$arResult['ID'];?>'>
    <div class='catalog-grey-block group'>
        <div class='catalog-detail-left-block'>
            <div class="item_slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?
                $images = array();

                if(is_array( $arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"] ) ){$images[] = $arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"];}
                foreach( $arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] as $arPhoto ){    $images[] = $arPhoto;}
                $bIsOneImage = count($images) == 1;
                ?>
                <?foreach( $images as $key => $arPhoto ){?>
                    <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
                        <?//pr($arPhoto); //$img = CFile::ResizeImageGet( $arPhoto, array( "width" => 1000, "height" => 800 ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, true, array() );?>
                       <?if($arResult['ID']!='1432'):?> <a rel='gallery' href="<?=$arPhoto["SRC"]?>"  class='fancy' > <?endif;?>
                            <?$img = CFile::ResizeImageGet( $arPhoto, array( "width" => 534, "height" => 307 ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true, array() );?>
                            <img border="0" src="<?=$img["src"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_ALT"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_TITLE"]?>" />
                        <?if($arResult['ID']!='1432'):?> </a>  <?endif;?>
                    </li>
                <?}?>
            </ul>
            <?if(count($images) > 1 ){?>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <ul id="thumbs">
                        <?foreach( $images as $key => $arPhoto ){?>
                            <?$img = CFile::ResizeImageGet( $arPhoto, array( "width" => 130, "height" => 76 ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true, array() );?>
                            <li <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
                                <a href='javascript:void(0);'>
                                    <img border="0" src="<?=$img["src"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?}?>
                        <?if (count($images)>3):?><?endif;?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <span class="thumbs_navigation"></span>
            <?}?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Битрикс... руки бы поотрывал их программистам...

Вы же можете проверить на пустоту массивы $arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] и $arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]? Если оба пусты, то показываем нужную картинку, если нет, то делаем приведенную Вами вакханалию.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
if(empty($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"]) && empty($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"])){
?>
  <img src="/bitrix/templates/site/images/wip.jpg" alt="" />
<?php
}else{
  //судя по всему остальной Ваш код
}
```

Comment: Можете подсказать, как это правильно прописать в template и после чего?

Comment: @Юрий, обновил комментарий, это просто общий принцип

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал логику обработки изображений вынести в result_modifier.php 
Тогда это будет выглядеть так:

result_modifier.php

```
<?php if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true){
    die();
}

$arResult['GALLERY'] = array();

$arImages = array();
if (is_array($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"])){
    $arImages[] = $arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"];
}
foreach ($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] as $arPhoto){
    $arImages[] = $arPhoto;
}

if (!empty($arImages)){
    foreach ($arImages as $k => $arImage){
        $arResult['GALLERY'][$k]['ORIGINAL'] = $arImage;
        $arResult['GALLERY'][$k]['BIG'] = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arImage, array(
            "width" => 534,
            "height" => 307
        ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true, array());
        $arResult['GALLERY'][$k]['SMALL'] = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arImage, array(
            "width" => 130,
            "height" => 76
        ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true, array());;
    }
    $arResult['GALLERY']['COUNT'] = count($arImages);
    unset($arImages);
}else{
    $arResult['GALLERY'][0]['ORIGINAL']['SRC'] = '/bitrix/templates/site/images/wip.jpg';
    $arResult['GALLERY'][0]['BIG']['src'] = '/bitrix/templates/site/images/wip.jpg';
    $arResult['GALLERY'][0]['SMALL']['src'] = '/bitrix/templates/site/images/wip.jpg';
    $arResult['GALLERY']['COUNT'] = 1;
}
?>
```

tempalte.php

```
<div class='catalog-detail' data-val='<?=$arResult['ID'];?>'>
    <div class='catalog-grey-block group'>
        <div class='catalog-detail-left-block'>
            <div class="item_slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <? foreach ($arResult['GALLERY'] as $key => $arPhoto){ ?>
                        <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
                            <? if ($arResult['ID'] != '1432'): ?>
                            <a rel='gallery' href="<?=$arPhoto["ORIGINAL"]["SRC"]?>" class='fancy'>
                                <? endif; ?>
                                <img border="0" src="<?=$arPhoto["BIG"]["src"]?>"
                                     alt="<?=$arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_ALT"]?>"
                                     title="<?=$arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_TITLE"]?>"/>
                                <? if ($arResult['ID'] != '1432'): ?>
                            </a>
                        <? endif; ?>
                        </li>
                    <? } ?>
                </ul>
                <? if ($arResult['GALLERY']['COUNT'] > 1){ ?>
                    <div class="thumbs">
                        <ul id="thumbs">
                            <? foreach ($arResult['GALLERY'] as $key => $arPhoto){ ?>
                                <li <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
                                    <a href='javascript:void(0);'>
                                        <img border="0" src="<?=$arPhoto["SMALL"]["src"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>"
                                             title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <? } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="thumbs_navigation"></span>
                <? } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: мне показалось это сложным решением. я не сильно в этом понимаю и в result modifier не хотелось бы туда еще лезть. по другому никак?